# Playing two audio files: syncing client-side or merging server-side?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I have two audio files that are user's input, and I'd like to play them in sync (instrumental + voice).

**Should I consider merging them server-side and play the result, or trigger a synchronized play of both files client-side ?**

Merging them will consume much more space (I want to keep the two audio files as well as the result).
Syncing would be great but I don't know if a client browser can handle it well (both files should stop playing if one is buffering, etc) because of Javascript's few milliseconds process time.

I would like to get pros and cons on this question.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use an audio library that helps you doing this client-side. [Buzz](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/documentation/buzz/) is an option.

Using the `all()` method should help you out.

Comment: Do you know if it handles client micro-lags or it just executes some audioElement.play() in a foreach ?